# Shortest hex dumping program

Tags: code-golf

#### Challenge

Create a console program to display each byte of a file.

---

#### Winning

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins.

---

#### Rules

- Program **must be a console application**, meaning that it will be ran from some sort of command-line interpreter;
- Every byte must be uppercase hexadecimal, separated by a space, and it must be 2 digits; *(put number 0 before it if it has 1 digit)*
- File **must be read** using IO or alternative, and not hard-coded;
- File path must be specified as a **command-line argument or a user prompt (like STDIN)**;
- **No [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) please**;

---

#### Example

test.txt (ends with LF)

```
Hello World!
```

```
$ ./hexdump.exe test.txt
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 0A
```

Comment: @facepalm42 To avoid facepalms, I strongly recommend using [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to help you design future challenges before posting them.

Comment: How is it possible to display all byte values at once, if it won't fit on the screen? Scrolling clearly isn't "at once". Also, what's wrong with (a function) just returning the values?

Comment: @facepalm42 Please don't change the spec so long time after posting the challenge. The original post didn't specify the exact format of the hexadecimal numbers, leaving it up to the answerers. Your latest edit invalidated my existing answer!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you only allow command-line argument or a user prompt? What's wrong with e.g. taking the file name as a function argument?

Comment: It would be helpful if you had a simple `hello.txt` text file as an example as an *input* and what the expected output should be. For instance, if the `hello.txt` contained simply the word `hello` with a line break, how would this be expressed in the output? Are you grouping the bytes in 16-bit,32-bit or 64-bit words? Or is each byte expressed as two-digit hex? Are spaces acceptable after each byte as hex, or after each x-bit word? Do you require an `0x` pre-fix for each byte?

Comment: I'm not sure about all the rules but would this in-browser JS solution taking a JS File object as input work for the "console application" and "command-line argument or a user prompt" points?  https://jsfiddle.net/xrbaohkz/1 It doesn't take care of the fetching and thus *reads* the file from the path that the browser made (be it to memory or disk). (Ps: not that this solution is good enough yet, but don't want to spend time on it if I'm blocked by these rules I'm not sure to understand)

Comment: What's a command line interpreter? Can I use a minecraft console?

Comment: Brainfuck doesn't have arguments, but this is trivial to implement with piping to stdin. Eg `beef hex.bf < test.txt`

Comment: @Sylwester But at that point you're taking input from STDIN, not as a command line argument as the question has unfortunately specified

Comment: @JoKing I have specified: "File path must be specified as a command-line argument or *a user prompt*". Which can be `stdin`.

Comment: @JoKing No, because the rules say "File must be read".

Comment: @JoKing I can't see anywhere where we specify the full contents as input? Just `test.txt` which is a filename.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96332/discussion-between-jo-king-and-facepalm42).

Answer (score 11):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) on *nix, <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```c
i;main(c,v)int**v;{for(c=open(v[1],0);read(c,&i,1);printf("%02X ",i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoQwDADAr4igNFJFvQb/sSAeSmwloK10pR7Erxud81C9EIkwboa9Ip2A/VFVCS8XoqIh7NarNHaTbgGjNfN3StYd4B6/6VRetP0vyzUD4C0iDYXZNgeHh9xqlr/U5ws) [Test suite](https://tio.run/##NYxBC8IgGEDv/ooPqdDh1rarW7e6dg0imJk2aepYtoLot5sdOj14PN5Z3Pt4lRLyJ@SvBGga2O530XArjCOSzdS4kGUzf2s/Edn6UTkyH6sTKymflLikZmVYRfk4pVITvCzrA2BmKOWfmF4IaTOotrO3oOzYISRFgA3gxU9jhIq1KPwj/EXs1TD4Lw)

*-2 bytes thanks to Johan du Toit*

This relies on `O_RDONLY == 0` and on `int_one == 1` where `int int_one; *(char*)&int_one = 1;`.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 11, <s>156</s> 154 bytes

```java
import java.nio.file.*;interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(int b:Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(a[0])))System.out.printf("%02X ",b);}}
```

-2 bytes thanks *to @Holger*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DY3LigIxEEX3fkUUhES0RlzqSmHEjSC4GEFclN2JVk861STlC/HbY7aXc85t8I6Tpv7PmdqOo6imDBCIwZG3MFpQEBsdVlZt30lQqFJ3plq1SEHvJVK4HE9o5Br5kdTvs7KdEIe346iLq87zdQkliBbrpferl9ikdyhXYKfxOD0ZY/avJLYFvgl0JShOD4bT2UENxmez@Hxy3ljvWf1x9HW/l@EHKHQFLkdf) by using `./.input.tio` as argument file-path, which will have a given input as file-content.

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.nio.file.*;        // Required import for Files and Paths
interface M{                   // Class
  static void main(String[]a)  //  Mandatory main method
      throws Exception{        //  With mandatory thrown clause for the readAllBytes builtin
                                         a[0]    // Get the first argument
                                 Path.of(    )   // Get the file using that argument as path
              Files.readAllBytes(             )  // Get all bytes from this file
    for(int b:                                 ) // Loop over each of them:
      System.out.printf(                         //  And print the current byte
                        "%02X ",b);}}            //  As uppercase hexadecimal with leading 0
                                                 //  and trailing space as delimiter
```

Comment: What's the rationale behind using `interface` instead of `class`?

Comment: @JakeDot main is required to be public, interface methods are always public, `interface` is shorter than `class` + `public`.

Comment: With Java 11, you can use `Path.of` instead of `Paths.get`

Comment: @Holger Thanks! :)

Comment: @JakeDot It's indeed as _Grimy_ said. `class M{public void main(...` is 3 bytes longer than `interface M{static void main(...`.

Comment: @Grimy since Java 9, interface methods are not always `public`, but they are `public` unless explicitly declared `private`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
$<.bytes{|b|$><<"%02X "%b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETv@YptULyUUnos0i/w2EOvG1ztwmJkEwNS@@1p9NTb8HjMjC5uzblqL26NFD6b26pH29r6enuBrd035w4hcZgRnqQU0GAihKgI0pA6irEggeTFQ/A6H85IU2SBAXVAkd05G0MQl5Jg5EU4FRKi8lTU3su@saNRuceEgNBzKIfwbmzXvD0cvSf4y/YH)

Comment: Does this read the contents of a file given a file-path as program argument? Based on the TIO it seems to just read from STDIN, but I don't know Ruby well-enough to say it's incorrect.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, it takes the file path(s) as program argument. If there are no arguments, `$<` switches to reading from STDIN instead.

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>60</s> <s>59</s> 54 bytes

```php
<?=wordwrap(bin2hex(implode(file($argv[1]))),2,' ',1);
```

- -1 byte thanks to manassehkatz
- -5 bytes thanks to Blackhole

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62PL8opbwosUAjKTPPKCO1QiMztyAnPyVVIy0zJ1VDJbEovSzaMFZTU1PHSEddQV3HUNP6/3@P1JycfIXw/KKcFMX/evp6mXkFpSV6JZn5AA)

Comment: Should be able to drop the trailing `?>` and save 2 bytes, or if that doesn't work then replace `?>` with a semicolon and save 1 byte.

Comment: Use `implode(file($x))` instead of `file_get_contents($x)` (-4 bytes).

Comment: And `wordwrap()`, with `1` as the last parameter, is one byte shorter than `chunk_split()`.

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>45</s> 40 bytes

```
"$(gc $args -ra|% *ay|%{'{0:X2}'-f+$_})"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lFIz1ZQSWxKL1YQbcosUZVQSuxska1Wr3awCrCqFZdN01bJb5WU@n/fw@g@nyF8PyinBRFrv96@nqZeQWlJXolmfkA)

*-5 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Comment: thanks for `./.input.tio`. [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X11dWyM9WUElsSi9WEG3KLFGVaFEq7JGtVq92sAqwqhWXTdNWyW@VvP/fw@g@nyF8PyinBRFrv96@nqZeQWlJXolmfkA "PowerShell – Try It Online") with CRLF preserved.

Comment: I learned this from the [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188002/68224).

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 5 (`-aF//`), 23 bytes

```
printf"%02X ",ord for@F
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1J1cAoQkFJJ78oRSEtv8jB7f9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBRFrn/5BSWZ@XnF/3UT3fT1AQ)

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 59 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to Mostly Harmless!

-8 bytes thanks to James K Polk!

-24 bytes thanks to Blue!

```python
print(' '.join('%02X'%ord(i)for i in open(input()).read()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcgxCoAwDADA3VfUoSRdougnfIKr0IqRkpRSB18fxc3p4MrdDpXZrFSWhuCATmVB8OO0gtcakcOu1bFjcVqSIEu5GoZANW3xNZjRQN9SY@2WlLP2v3sA)

This is pretty straightforward; it opens a filename given as input on STDIN, reads it, converts each character to its ASCII value, converts each number to hex, strips off the `"0x"` that precedes hexademical values in Python, pads the value with a zero if necessary, then joins the values together with spaces.

Comment: Can save a few bytes with `'%02X'%ord(i)` instead of slicing the output of hex

Comment: @MostlyHarmless Done! -11 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: how about '%02X' instead of '%02x', and get rid of `.upper()`

Comment: You can save the bytes from the `import sys` by using `raw_input()` as the filename instead; rules allow user prompting.

Comment: @Blue Thanks! And it's even shorter in Python 3, where you can just do `input()`

Comment: Drat `f'{ord(i):02X}'` is like 2 chars longer then `'%02X'%ord(i)` and loading as a byte stream doesn't save anything either e.g. `print(' '.join(f'{i:02X}'for i in open(input(),'br').read()))`

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Returns (and implicitly prints, if the value isn't otherwise consumed) a two-row matrix with the top 4 bits represented as a decimal number 0–15 in the top row and the bottom 4 bits similarly represented in the bottom row. That is, the matrix has as many columns as the file has bytes.

```apl
16 16⊤83 ¯1∘⎕MAP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@v7pGak5OvoxCeX5SToqj@qG@qX0BoiHpJboFeSUWJ@n9DMwVDs0ddSyyMFQ6tN3zUMQOowtcx4H/ao7YJj3r7gDxP/0ddzYfWGz9qmwjkBQc5A8kQD8/g/2lwUwA)

`⎕MAP` map the argument filename to an array
`∘` with parameters:
`¯1` the entire length of the file
`83` read as 8-bit integers

`16 16⊤` convert (anti-base) to 2-position hexadecimal

Comment: @facepalm42 It very much is in hexadecimal. E.g. `H` is 72, which is 4×16¹+8×16⁰ or [4,8]₁₆. Hence the first column in the example reads `[4,8]`.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot! Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/),  <s>33</s>  23 bytes

...with a lot of help:
-3 thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198)
-4 thanks to [spuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87944)
-3 thanks to [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745)

```bash
echo `xxd -c1 -p -u $1`
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18hoaIiRUE32VBBt0BBt1RBxTDh/3@P1JycfIXw/KKcFEUurvCixAKFpNTK/LwUhfLMlJIMhfw0BaAuPQA)**

Note that the TIO link above uses input - we can write files locally, so [this](https://tio.run/##NYxBDoMgFET3nGKamLiCxhW7rnsDtyofSxP0E8RIT48a0tVkMu/NNG6uWOMY7dt6z@g5enoI0ccxYLI/XgnHl5IDz8iZVIsX0hJUyklUsfrDNUKaDjJA7mi6odxoiPwRxi1M0FrXqp53/F/KCQ) shows it working as a program taking a file path.

Comment: Minor reductions: `xxd -u -p $1|fold -2|tr \\n \ `.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to get the `\n` and `\ ` to work in the 'this' link version? EDIT: I added another escape character.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to change from double quotes to single quotes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsIwFEX3fMW1CJ0a0SWbs3/QJUvblxoh7QvxiRH67zEqTpdz4ZxxuPviJs9oLi4ERs8p0E6pPg0Ro3vxSnjeSDx4Rs6kG5whS9SSRX3FttQb3QNdxP64zRwqnTZJsHaFRWmrERNf1eQXJhhjfqgPn/nHyhs "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Awesome thank you!

Comment: `xxd -c1 -p -u $1|tr \\n \ `

Comment: maybe `echo \`xxd -c1 -p -u $1\``, if newline at the end is allowed

Comment: @spuck - I looked at `-c` for a no-limit option but didn't think of restricting to 1, thanks!

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I can't see anything forbidding that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>130</s> <s>127</s> <s>104</s> <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){java.io.File(a[0]).readBytes().forEach{print("%02X ".format(it))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCsJADADQ3a84C8LdEoujiKCguDsoiEOwV41eLyWmQin99qjr471YE2WzusuuQcoelxsR7FdHFcr3dRie@EEghj2l6PFSXgNIxGrba3z7ADXLDm@Pof119cWsXJxd8dcG1ZOGMI5mh5gSuxNLqqYTgzlQbjsFJf4C)

Edit: -11 bytes thanks to @ChrisParton

Edit: Working TIO

Edit: -1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen

Comment: Could you ditch the import and reference `File` as `java.io.File` instead?

Comment: @ChrisParton right you are, thanks!

Comment: [Here a working TIO.](https://tio.run/##FcqxCsJADADQ3a84C8LdEoujiKCguDsoiEOwV41eLyWmQin99qjr471YE2WzusuuQcoel24jgv3qqEL5vg7DEz8IxLCnFD1eymsAiVhte41vH6Bm2eHtMbS/rr6YlYuzK/7aoHrSEMbR7BBTYndiSdV0YjAHym2noMRf) You can use `./.input.tio` as file-path argument, and it will use the STDIN as file-content. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks! just updated answer

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but the TIO still works if I remove the space at `a:Array`, so I think you can save a byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh haha, whoops yeah I can totally save a byte there thanks, rookie mistake

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>145</s> 143 bytes

```haskell
import System.Environment
import Text.Printf
import Data.ByteString
main=getArgs>>=Data.ByteString.readFile.(!!0)>>=mapM_(printf"%02X ").unpack
```

Comment: A little bit shorter: `import Data.ByteString` plus `main=getArgs>>=Data.ByteString.readFile.(!!0)>>=mapM_(printf"%02X ").unpack`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>140</s> 134 bytes

```
import'dart:io';main(a){print(new File(a[0]).readAsBytesSync().map((n)=>n.toRadixString(16).toUpperCase().padLeft(2,'0')).join(' '));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYuxCgIxEAV/5brsgoTTwsJDQQUrKw8rsViSVXN6SUgW9BC/PaZ7M8yzlKQUN8aQRNkKKxdUZx5snkD4jcl5Ac/v5uBeDHRpr6gTk93m3SSc@8kbQD1SBPC43ngt4UTWfXqpzzvMl1jNOUZOe8pc00j2yDeBxUy1ClEPwXlQTZ3dr5Q/)

-6 bytes because I forgot to reduce variable names

Comment: +1 for dart. Such an underrated language.

Comment: Hard to golf with, since it's basically JS without the very lax type system

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 45 bytes

```
@*ARGS[0].IO.slurp(:bin).list.fmt('%02X').say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99ByzHIPTjaIFbP01@vOKe0qEDDKikzT1MvJ7O4RC8tt0RDXdXAKEJdU684sfL/f4/UnJx8HYXy/KKcFMX/evp6mXkFpSV6JZn5AA)

- `@*ARGS[0]` is the first command-line argument.
- `.IO` turns that (presumed) filename into an `IO::Path` object.
- `.slurp(:bin)` reads the entire file into a `Buf` buffer of bytes.  (Without the `:bin` the file contents would be returned as a Unicode string.)
- `.list` returns a list of the byte values from the buffer.
- `.fmt('%02X')` is a `List` method that formats the elements of the list using the given format string, then joins them with spaces.  (Convenient!)
- `.say` prints that string.

Comment: Based on the Python answer, a [TIO Link](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99ByzHIPTjaIFbP01@vOKe0qEDDKikzT1MvJ7O4RC8tt0RDXdXAKEJdU684sfL/f4/UnJx8HYXy/KKcFMX/evp6mXkFpSV6JZn5AA) is in fact quite possible.

Comment: Some rearranging can remove the `.list` for [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhLbdEocZByzHIPTjaIFbP01@vOKe0qEDDKikzT9NKQV3VwChC/f9/j9ScnHwdhfL8opwUxf96@nqZeQWlJXolmfkA)

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 141 bytes (contributed version)

```
use std::{io::*,fs::*,env::*};fn main(){for x in File::open(args().nth(1).unwrap()).unwrap().bytes(){print!("{:02X} ",x.unwrap())}println!()}
```

## Rust, 151 bytes (original version)

```
fn main(){std::io::Read::bytes(std::fs::File::open(std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap()).unwrap()).map(|x|print!("{:02X} ",x.unwrap())).count();println!()}
```

Comment: -10 bytes: [TIO](https://tio.run/##RYrLDsIgEEV/ZdoVmAYfS9wb/0C3mFKdBAcCg9YQvh2rm27OPck9MSduLScLiUetC3qtN8OUfrT0WqYeJ4KnQRKyTD7CDEhwQme19sGSMPGehFTED7GXKtM7miDkaur2YbsUJUQk7kRf9O5wrdAP81rX/@moE7K2drbOebj46Mauqa1CCpkVo/8C)

Answer (score 2):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), <s>186</s> 162 bytes

```
filesb❗️❗️b❗️➕256 16❗️1 2❗️ ❗️❗️
```

Try it online [here.](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9JNfv//8P8ycvSMnNSiz/M718AxI0f5ve2f5g/pSkJyNgFlAVyJgDx5JYP89umAiUWfpg/sQmocM@judPf7@iHkBBNE4FqJq8GslcB1a2CqJ2yKAmqcN5UI1MzBUMzCNdQwQimdcoSBRAB0odmZicI//@vl5lXUFqiV5KZDwA)

Ungolfed:

```
 files    Import the files package into the default namespace
    Main code block
 b   For each b in ...
     (ignoring IO errors)
       ... the byte representation of the file ...
       ... read from user input:
  ❗️ ❗️ 
       Print ...
       ... in upper case (numbers in bases > 10 are in lower case) ...
       ... the concatenation of:
         b ❗️ ➕ 256   b + 256 (this gives the leading zero in case the hex representation of b is a single digit) ...
              16   ... represented in hexadecimal ...
           ❗️
         1 2   ... without the leading one,
      ❗️
          ... and a space
    
    ❗️❗️
```

Answer (score 2):

### bash+Stax, 6+4+1=11 bytes

This is complete theory craft at this point. You can't actually run this. If everything works according to its spec this would work, but not everything does yet.

The bash script is

```
]<$1
```

and the stax program must be compiled and saved to ] is

```
╛↕ßú┼_
```

Set your character set to ISO 8859-1 (Windows-1252 won't work here) and go

Unpacked and explained

```
_          push all input as a single array
F          run the rest of the program for each element of the array
 |H        write the hex of the byte to standard output
 |         write a space to standard output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Node.js, 118 bytes

```
console.log([...require("fs").readFileSync(process.argv[2])].map(y=>(y<16?0:"")+y.toString(16).toUpperCase()).join` `)
```

What the result looks like:
[image]

Btw the content of `test.txt` in the example is as follows:

> `做乜嘢要輸出大楷姐，搞到要加番toUpperCase()去轉番，咁就13byte啦。`
>  (Why on earth is upper-case output necessary. I had to add the conversion with `toUpperCase()`, and that cost 13 bytes.)

Comment: using `...` for an array is actually pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 75 bytes

Mostly a copy of [Maxwell's python 2 answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188074/3139)

```
import sys
print(' '.join('%02X'%b for b in open(sys.argv[1],'rb').read()))
```

Comment: you mean probably `sys.argv[1]`. with `sys.argv[0]` this script works more like a quine ;-)

Comment: @anion: oops, haha, fixing ...

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org), 98 Bytes

```
import std;void main(string[]s){File(s[1]).byChunk(9).joiner.each!(a=>writef("%02X ",a.to!byte));}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCsIwEADQq6QFIYEyfnZSdCOIN1AoXaRmtFPTTEmmShHPHt9zOdM4cRSVxNVvJqdGS0EniRSeTZvM90wedWq2rYFuOfVzeOm9gYEpYAS0977Q9nD8RBJ86HK12d1UWVkQLrpF0Jj6l/MFvedKXTl6V2RYA4VpFhDiPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 71 bytes

```forth
: f slurp-file hex 0 do dup c@ 0 <# # # #> type space 1+ loop ;
1 arg f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@7DsIwDEV3vuJSRlQeYgOEGPkDli5R4rSVDI6cVIWvD23pgIQ8@Orq6Fj2oqkpaz@uHAskeoSNH4Jue1glk6j0LROcSoDrAmJV4EbMgrsou2X1LFQSem3/UM9dbH46yxJnpprlMNNJjGU@wiNyp@HLNPTCDk4ml70O@bzCNBekdyDEYCxhvwbLYD8tDjBaw@ec5zc@)

*TIO has `3 arg` in the last line because TIO passes "-e bye" to the command line parser before passing in the code*

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f             \ start a function definition
  slurp-file    \ open the file indicated by the string on top of the stack,
                \ then put its contents  in a new string on top of the stack
  hex           \ set the interpreter to base 16
  0 do          \ loop from 0 to file-length - 1 (inclusive)
    dup c@      \ get the character value from the address on top of the stack
    0 <# # # #> \ convert to a double-length number then convert to a string of length 2
    type        \ output the created string 
    space       \ output a space 
    1+          \ add 1 to the current address value
  loop          \ end the loop
;               \ end the word definition
1 arg f         \ get the filename from the first command-line argument and call the function
```

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 144 bytes

This submission does output a trailing space, and no trailing newline. Let me know if this is considered a loophole :)

```rkt
(command-line #:args(f)(for([b(call-with-input-file f port->bytes)])(printf"~a "(string-upcase(~r b #:base 16 #:min-width 2 #:pad-string"0")))))
```

### Cleaned up

```rkt
(command-line #:args (f)
 (for ([b (call-with-input-file f port->bytes)])
   (printf "~a "
           (string-upcase
            (~r b #:base 16 #:min-width 2 #:pad-string "0")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 155 bytes

```
for(b=WScript,a=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(b.Arguments(0));;b.echo(('0'+a.read(1).charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript, 143 bytes

```
set a=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0)):while 1 WScript.echo(right("0"+Hex(Asc(a.read(1))),2)):wend
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>94</s> 89 bytes

```
Print@ToUpperCase@StringRiffle@IntegerString[BinaryReadList@Last@$ScriptCommandLine,16,2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcixCsIwEADQ3a9QcAwRHZyDXRQ6SKs4iMPRXutBcgnXc/Drz4DLG14CfWMCpQHMrkKs4ZbvpaA0sGDotdbc0TRFDBdWnFH@9zwRg3w7hLGlRUMLlW0/CBVtckrA9Rnd/ugOL7Mzxpjd@pEljpuV@Z0nLh/1SvkH)

The code is quite self-explanatory because of the long command names. It should be read mostly from right to left:

```
$ScriptCommandLine       is a list of {scriptname, commandlinearg1, commandlinearg2, ...}
Last@...                 extracts the last command-line argument
BinaryReadList@...       reads the named file into a list of bytes
IntegerString[...,16,2]  converts each byte to a 2-digit hex string (lowercase)
StringRiffle@...         converts this list of strings into a single string with spaces
ToUpperCase@...          converts the string to uppercase
Print@...                prints the result to stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 45 characters

```
?=@fill-right{00;@radix{10;16;@char-int{?}}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '?=@fill-right{00;@radix{10;16;@char-int{?}}} ' <<< 'Hello World!'
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 0A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/397WIS0zJ0e3KDM9o6TawMDaoSgxJbOi2tDA2tDM2iE5I7FINzOvpNq@trZW4f9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
jdcr1.Hjb'w2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PysluchQzyMrSb3c6P9//fyCEv0CoASY0CuoBAA)

Takes input as user prompt (no way to access command-line arguments AFAIK).

```
jd           # join on spaces
  c        2 # chop into pieces of length 2
   r1        # convert to uppercase
     .H      # convert to hex string, interpreting as base 256 (*)
       jb    # join on newlines
         '   # read file as list of lines
          w  # input()
```

(*) I'm not 100% sure if this is intended, but one base 256 digit (as in, one character), will always convert into exactly 2 hex digits, eliminating the need to pad with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

#### [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/) [.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com) Framework 4.7.2 - <s>235</s> <s>213</s> <s>203</s> <s>191</s> <s>175</s> 140 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc3BagIxEIDhe59iugdJ0AbpdaGgolhosXQLFpY9zGajDqRJyYyiLH32dBHxP3/wW36ybHM@MoU9VBcW92NeN6X1yAwfPQsKWThF6uAdKSiWNMi6Qd3TTqF5c2Evh5fpaLQi78zyTCyssJ42Wve7mBzagzphghYowNV8Ouxm3s8v4u7ydl7EwHEg20TiVGu@YnX9qeL7udDjAgpd/g3lvHbexwlsY/Ld40M2FH6PYoTiPw)

```
using System.IO;class P{static void Main(string[]a){foreach(var b in File.ReadAllBytes(a[0])){System.Console.Write(b.ToString("X2")+" ");}}}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace hexdump
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Read the bytes of the file
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(args[0]);

            // Loop through all the bytes and show them
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                // Show the byte converted to hexadecimal
                Console.Write(b.ToString("X2") + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the following will save some bytes (now 181 I think):

using System.IO;class P{static void Main(string[] a){if(a.Length>0 && File.Exists(a[0])){foreach(var b in File.ReadAllBytes(a[0])){System.Console.Write($"{b.ToString("X2")} ");}}}}

Comment: @PmanAce If you remove some of the whitespace, it gets down to 175.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
IvyÇh2j' 0.:' Jvy?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fs6zycHuGUZa6goGelbqCV1ml/f//rB6pOTn5CuH5RTkprAA)

Explanation:

```
IvyÇh2j' 0.:' Jvy?
Iv                 Loop through each character in input
  y                Push current character
   Ç               ASCII value
    h              Convert to hexadecimal
     2j            Pad with at least 2 spaces
       ' 0.:       Replace all spaces with 0s
            ' J    Add space to end
               vy? Convert to string and print
IvyÇh2j' 0.:' Jvy?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Free Pascal](https://www.freepascal.org/), 81 B

```pascal
var c:char;begin while not EOF do begin read(c);write(hexStr(ord(c),2):3)end end.
```

Note, output has a leading blank and no trailing newline:
 `48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 0A`

---

**−3 B**:
By default the FPC (FreePascal Compiler) has the “FPC compiler compatibility mode” selected.
When compiling in FPC’s “ISO standard compiler compatibility mode” the file buffer variables (here specifically `input^`) and “low-level” I/O routines like `get` become available.
The following code needs to be compiled with `fpc ‑MISO sourceCode.pas`:

```pascal
begin while not EOF do begin write(hexStr(ord(input^),2):3);get(input)end end.
```

---

**−10 B**: *Furthermore*, *if* `input` was guaranteed to be non-empty, we can use a `repeat … until …` loop instead of the bulky `while … do begin … end`:

```pascal
begin repeat write(hexStr(ord(input^),2):3);get(input)until EOF end.
```